# Types of algirthms using to predict item inventory stock

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, prediction

I want to predict stock by analyzing stock mouvement.
Stock mouvement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfCcN.png)

STOCK :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE1ts.png)

Which step to start analzying data using machine learning.
Which algorithme ML and DL to use.

Thanks a lot

I need :
learn step to start analzying data using machine learning and deep learning.
Type of algorithme ML and DL to use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mohamed:
Your question requires a long and broad answer.  I'll try to provide some steps and reference for you to explore further.
First of all you need the right data.  The prediction will be as good as your data.  So you need economic data, market trends, and company-specific events.
Then you need to follow the standard steps:
Collect and Preprocess Data: You'll need to gather stock data such as daily closing prices, trading volumes, and other relevant financial information. Preprocessing the data involves cleaning and transforming the data so that it can be used for modeling.

```
Feature Engineering: This involves creating new features from the existing data that can be used as inputs for the ML/DL models. For example, you can calculate technical indicators such as moving averages, relative strength index (RSI), and Bollinger Bands.

Split the Data: You'll need to split the data into training, validation, and testing sets. The training set is used to train the ML/DL models, the validation set is used to fine-tune the models, and the testing set is used to evaluate the performance of the models.

Select an Algorithm: There are various ML algorithms that can be used for stock price prediction. Some popular algorithms include:
ML Algorithms: Linear Regression, Random Forest, XGBoost, Support Vector Machines (SVM), etc.
```

Hope that helps.

Reference Book: https://learning.oreilly.com/api/v1/continue/9781800560796/
Machine Learning Engineering with MLflow - Chapter 2